# Clear Cache in FRAMESET

Tags: javascript, html, caching, coldfusion

I have 2 frames. I have used history.go in by back button click. Now, I have to use clear cache option for all history.go pages. I have used below. But no hope.

My technology is CF. I ve tried CFHEADER. No use.

```
<cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="cache-control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
```

My frame is like

```
 <frameset> <f1> <f2> </frameset->

<f1> used to show loading text
<f2> used to show content.
```

Pls let me know how to clear cache in FRAMESET

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you believe it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

Comment: I ve tried both in CFHEADER and <meta tags. no use.